# SQL query - Records has at least one of the relationships specified - alternative?

Tags: sql, performance

I have 4 tables `person`, `employments`, `properties`, `memberships`

How can I filter people that have at least one of the three relationships above?

What I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM people p
WHERE p.id IN (SELECT e.person_id FROM employments e WHERE e.person_id = p.id)
   OR p.id IN (SELECT pr.person_id FROM person_properties pr WHERE pr.person_id = p.id)
   OR p.id IN (SELECT m.person_id FROM union_memberships m WHERE m.person_id = p.id)
```

Seems to be working, but it looks odd, and I am not sure if it's the most efficient way of doing it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IN` clauses are redundant.  You have a correlation clause and then are checking *the same column* for `IN`.  This could confuse the optimizer (but probably not).

This is a simpler way to express the logic:

```
SELECT * 
FROM people p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employments e WHERE e.person_id = p.id) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM person_properties pr WHERE pr.person_id = p.id) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM union_memberships m WHERE m.person_id = p.id);
```

I would be surprised, however, if this had a noticeable affect on performance.

For performance, you want indexes on:

- `employments(person_id)`
- `person_properties(person_id)`
- `union_memberships(person_id)`.

Comment: Thanks, actually had changed to exists yesterday, will try the indexes!